# Android app shows debug options with release build

Tags: react-native

I build an app with `./gradlew assembleRelease` and then running this app shows debug options.

*This is for android app only.*

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

I expect it will not show debug options but they are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to android>>app>>build>>outputs>>apk and try to find your apk release there, if it says apk-release-unsigned.apk or somethign similar it means you have not done the steps to generate a key // change things for a release build check the official [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) and this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/bundling-react-native-during-android-release-builds-ec52c24e200d)

Comment: I have an **apk** in _release folder_ with name app-release.apk.

Comment: Um, are u using it with a custom app or the default one ? , do you have some native android modules installed ? something messed up the main activity ... or maybe... somethign stupid that also happened to me, i needed to uninstall the app from the phone before react-native run-android because it was not updating ;-;. Also try this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17522

Comment: Thanks @ValdaXD, adding **debuggable false** in gradle worked :)